# Getting cURL result in MFC C++

Tags: curl, mfc

I'm trying to messagebox the cURL result:

```
    CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
        curl_easy_strerror(res));
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
MessageBox(res, _T("Title"), MB_ICONASTERISK | MB_OK);
```

How can i messagebox the res value ?

Comment: What is the error? What is `CURLcode` class?

Comment: i get some chinese weird characters instead of result

Answer (score 0):

```
        CString str(readBuffer.c_str());

    statictext.SetWindowTextW(LPCTSTR(str));
    MessageBox(LPCTSTR(str), _T("Title"), MB_ICONASTERISK | MB_OK);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Finally found a way!